Emotional Differentiation function R error "Error in stack.data.frame(x) : no vector columns were selected"
I'm attempting to follow an emotional differentiation code for momentary emotional differentiation. I've been getting a strange error "Error in stack.data.frame(x) : no vector columns were selected" when running it on my data. I have tried to contact the authors of this function directly but have not gotten a response. I have since followed their preprocessing and I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong. Does anyone know why this error might be coming up?
## Install packages
# ipak function: install and load multiple R packages.
packages <- c("ggplot2","psych","nlme","pracma", "corrplot","lattice","R2HTML", "zoo","psy", "sjstats", "dplyr", "plyr", "tidyverse", "magrittr", "grid", "readxl", "haven", "tseries", "lmtest","car", "interactions", "lme4", "irr") 
##
ipak <- function(pkg){
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg)) 
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
  sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE) }
ipak(packages)
## 
## This look loads the libraries 
for (pkg in packages ) library(pkg, character.only=T)

meal_only_emo <- structure(list(record_id = structure(c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), label = "Record ID", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 26L), 
    Alert = structure(c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 11L), 
    Inspired = structure(c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2), format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 11L), 
    Determined = structure(c(2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2), format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 11L), 
    Attentive = structure(c(2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3), format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 11L), 
    Active = structure(c(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3), format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 11L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`7` = 7L, 
`13` = 13L, `15` = 15L, `20` = 20L, `35` = 35L, `46` = 46L, `59` = 59L, 
`76` = 76L, `81` = 81L, `86` = 86L, `87` = 87L, `89` = 89L, `98` = 98L, 
`99` = 99L, `108` = 108L, `112` = 112L, `117` = 117L, `121` = 121L, 
`126` = 126L, `127` = 127L, `132` = 132L, `133` = 133L, `136` = 136L, 
`144` = 144L, `145` = 145L, `154` = 154L, `157` = 157L, `174` = 174L, 
`204` = 204L, `208` = 208L, `214` = 214L, `215` = 215L, `217` = 217L, 
`225` = 225L, `228` = 228L, `229` = 229L, `238` = 238L, `242` = 242L, 
`245` = 245L, `249` = 249L, `256` = 256L, `261` = 261L, `262` = 262L, 
`263` = 263L, `264` = 264L, `269` = 269L, `274` = 274L, `275` = 275L, 
`280` = 280L, `282` = 282L, `284` = 284L, `287` = 287L, `289` = 289L, 
`293` = 293L, `302` = 302L, `328` = 328L, `356` = 356L, `383` = 383L, 
`384` = 384L, `385` = 385L, `386` = 386L, `392` = 392L, `394` = 394L, 
`396` = 396L, `400` = 400L, `401` = 401L, `407` = 407L, `410` = 410L, 
`413` = 413L, `419` = 419L, `421` = 421L, `435` = 435L, `436` = 436L, 
`437` = 437L, `438` = 438L, `443` = 443L, `444` = 444L, `449` = 449L, 
`466` = 466L, `469` = 469L, `473` = 473L, `476` = 476L, `480` = 480L, 
`486` = 486L, `499` = 499L, `508` = 508L, `514` = 514L, `515` = 515L, 
`516` = 516L, `517` = 517L, `518` = 518L, `519` = 519L, `520` = 520L, 
`545` = 545L, `573` = 573L, `574` = 574L, `577` = 577L, `578` = 578L, 
`631` = 631L, `672` = 672L, `676` = 676L, `682` = 682L, `683` = 683L, 
`684` = 684L, `690` = 690L, `695` = 695L, `717` = 717L, `728` = 728L, 
`730` = 730L, `731` = 731L, `733` = 733L, `735` = 735L, `740` = 740L, 
`741` = 741L, `742` = 742L, `743` = 743L, `744` = 744L, `745` = 745L, 
`746` = 746L, `749` = 749L, `753` = 753L, `760` = 760L, `762` = 762L, 
`773` = 773L, `775` = 775L, `785` = 785L, `787` = 787L, `790` = 790L, 
`793` = 793L, `798` = 798L, `809` = 809L, `810` = 810L, `813` = 813L, 
`818` = 818L, `821` = 821L, `824` = 824L, `834` = 834L, `845` = 845L, 
`846` = 846L, `890` = 890L, `891` = 891L, `892` = 892L, `894` = 894L, 
`895` = 895L, `896` = 896L, `897` = 897L, `898` = 898L, `899` = 899L, 
`900` = 900L, `901` = 901L, `902` = 902L, `903` = 903L, `904` = 904L, 
`905` = 905L, `906` = 906L, `909` = 909L, `912` = 912L, `913` = 913L, 
`915` = 915L, `916` = 916L, `919` = 919L, `920` = 920L, `921` = 921L, 
`924` = 924L, `925` = 925L, `927` = 927L, `928` = 928L, `929` = 929L, 
`930` = 930L, `931` = 931L, `932` = 932L, `933` = 933L, `934` = 934L, 
`935` = 935L, `936` = 936L, `937` = 937L, `938` = 938L, `939` = 939L, 
`940` = 940L, `941` = 941L, `942` = 942L, `943` = 943L, `944` = 944L, 
`945` = 945L, `946` = 946L, `947` = 947L, `948` = 948L, `949` = 949L, 
`950` = 950L, `951` = 951L, `952` = 952L, `953` = 953L, `954` = 954L, 
`955` = 955L, `956` = 956L, `960` = 960L, `962` = 962L, `967` = 967L, 
`970` = 970L, `974` = 974L, `976` = 976L, `978` = 978L, `984` = 984L, 
`985` = 985L, `990` = 990L, `993` = 993L, `995` = 995L, `997` = 997L, 
`1001` = 1001L, `1006` = 1006L, `1009` = 1009L, `1011` = 1011L, 
`1013` = 1013L, `1016` = 1016L, `1019` = 1019L, `1030` = 1030L, 
`1032` = 1032L, `1033` = 1033L, `1036` = 1036L, `1039` = 1039L, 
`1044` = 1044L, `1045` = 1045L, `1050` = 1050L, `1051` = 1051L, 
`1053` = 1053L, `1055` = 1055L, `1056` = 1056L, `1080` = 1080L, 
`1081` = 1081L, `1082` = 1082L, `1083` = 1083L, `1084` = 1084L, 
`1085` = 1085L, `1087` = 1087L, `1092` = 1092L, `1094` = 1094L, 
`1096` = 1096L, `1097` = 1097L, `1098` = 1098L, `1102` = 1102L, 
`1103` = 1103L, `1104` = 1104L, `1108` = 1108L, `1109` = 1109L, 
`1110` = 1110L, `1115` = 1115L, `1116` = 1116L, `1122` = 1122L, 
`1123` = 1123L, `1124` = 1124L, `1125` = 1125L, `1126` = 1126L, 
`1135` = 1135L, `1138` = 1138L, `1215` = 1215L, `1216` = 1216L, 
`1217` = 1217L, `1218` = 1218L, `1219` = 1219L, `1220` = 1220L, 
`1222` = 1222L, `1223` = 1223L, `1225` = 1225L, `1229` = 1229L, 
`1230` = 1230L, `1232` = 1232L, `1234` = 1234L, `1235` = 1235L, 
`1239` = 1239L, `1241` = 1241L, `1245` = 1245L, `1246` = 1246L, 
`1249` = 1249L, `1250` = 1250L, `1251` = 1251L, `1301` = 1301L, 
`1323` = 1323L, `1327` = 1327L, `1344` = 1344L, `1360` = 1360L, 
`1361` = 1361L, `1362` = 1362L, `1363` = 1363L, `1364` = 1364L, 
`1365` = 1365L, `1366` = 1366L, `1368` = 1368L, `1370` = 1370L, 
`1371` = 1371L, `1372` = 1372L, `1374` = 1374L, `1376` = 1376L, 
`1377` = 1377L, `1379` = 1379L, `1380` = 1380L, `1382` = 1382L, 
`1383` = 1383L, `1384` = 1384L, `1388` = 1388L, `1391` = 1391L, 
`1394` = 1394L, `1395` = 1395L, `1397` = 1397L, `1398` = 1398L, 
`1401` = 1401L, `1405` = 1405L, `1407` = 1407L, `1409` = 1409L, 
`1410` = 1410L, `1411` = 1411L, `1412` = 1412L, `1413` = 1413L, 
`1415` = 1415L, `1417` = 1417L, `1461` = 1461L, `1467` = 1467L, 
`1514` = 1514L, `1537` = 1537L, `1540` = 1540L, `1583` = 1583L, 
`1584` = 1584L, `1589` = 1589L, `1594` = 1594L, `1603` = 1603L, 
`1614` = 1614L, `1622` = 1622L, `1636` = 1636L, `1639` = 1639L, 
`1643` = 1643L, `1645` = 1645L, `1646` = 1646L, `1647` = 1647L, 
`1696` = 1696L, `1702` = 1702L, `1708` = 1708L, `1734` = 1734L, 
`1750` = 1750L, `1751` = 1751L, `1752` = 1752L, `1755` = 1755L, 
`1759` = 1759L, `1760` = 1760L, `1766` = 1766L, `1769` = 1769L, 
`1773` = 1773L, `1784` = 1784L, `1785` = 1785L, `1787` = 1787L, 
`1806` = 1806L, `1808` = 1808L, `1810` = 1810L, `1816` = 1816L, 
`1817` = 1817L, `1829` = 1829L, `1830` = 1830L, `1834` = 1834L, 
`1837` = 1837L, `1838` = 1838L, `1842` = 1842L, `1844` = 1844L, 
`1852` = 1852L, `1855` = 1855L, `1856` = 1856L, `1858` = 1858L, 
`1862` = 1862L, `1867` = 1867L, `1869` = 1869L, `1871` = 1871L, 
`1874` = 1874L, `1875` = 1875L, `1880` = 1880L, `1882` = 1882L, 
`1884` = 1884L, `1887` = 1887L, `1889` = 1889L, `1891` = 1891L, 
`1892` = 1892L, `1896` = 1896L, `1916` = 1916L, `1918` = 1918L, 
`1923` = 1923L, `1951` = 1951L, `1956` = 1956L, `1964` = 1964L, 
`1996` = 1996L, `1997` = 1997L, `1999` = 1999L, `2000` = 2000L, 
`2004` = 2004L, `2009` = 2009L, `2015` = 2015L, `2019` = 2019L, 
`2021` = 2021L, `2026` = 2026L, `2033` = 2033L, `2039` = 2039L, 
`2042` = 2042L, `2061` = 2061L, `2062` = 2062L, `2063` = 2063L, 
`2100` = 2100L, `2102` = 2102L, `2105` = 2105L, `2107` = 2107L, 
`2120` = 2120L, `2123` = 2123L, `2125` = 2125L, `2129` = 2129L, 
`2130` = 2130L, `2136` = 2136L, `2140` = 2140L, `2141` = 2141L, 
`2146` = 2146L, `2148` = 2148L, `2154` = 2154L, `2158` = 2158L, 
`2159` = 2159L, `2160` = 2160L, `2161` = 2161L, `2162` = 2162L, 
`2164` = 2164L, `2165` = 2165L, `2168` = 2168L, `2173` = 2173L, 
`2182` = 2182L, `2186` = 2186L, `2193` = 2193L, `2195` = 2195L, 
`2200` = 2200L, `2202` = 2202L, `2206` = 2206L, `2213` = 2213L, 
`2215` = 2215L, `2218` = 2218L, `2225` = 2225L, `2229` = 2229L, 
`2230` = 2230L, `2231` = 2231L, `2234` = 2234L, `2247` = 2247L, 
`2249` = 2249L, `2255` = 2255L, `2262` = 2262L, `2266` = 2266L, 
`2270` = 2270L, `2273` = 2273L, `2276` = 2276L, `2280` = 2280L, 
`2282` = 2282L, `2284` = 2284L, `2288` = 2288L, `2296` = 2296L, 
`2297` = 2297L, `2345` = 2345L), class = "omit"))

calculate_ed <- function(dat, emotions, ..., allow_neg_icc = FALSE, fisher_transform_icc = TRUE) {
  
  center <- function(x){
    x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  
  dat$row_id <- 1:nrow(dat)
  
  c_dat <- dat %>% group_by(...) %>% mutate(across(emotions, center))
  
  # Calculate person-level metrics
  
  person_dat <- c_dat %>% group_by(...) %>% group_split( .keep = TRUE) %>% lapply(., function(x)
    # Keep the ID vars
    cbind(x %>% select(row_id, ...),
          
          # Calculate emotional variance
          m_emo_var = sum(diag(var(x[, emotions]))),
          # Calculate classic (non) ED
          c_nonED = psych::ICC(x[emotions], missing = TRUE, lmer = F)$results[6, 2]
          
    )) %>%
    do.call('rbind', .)
  
  c_dat <- left_join(c_dat, person_dat)
  
  c_dat$momentary_squared_sum <- c_dat[emotions] %>% apply(., 1, function(x) (mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)*length(emotions))^2)
  
  c_dat$m_nonED <- c_dat$momentary_squared_sum/c_dat$m_emo_var
  c_dat$m_ED <- c_dat$momentary_squared_sum/c_dat$m_emo_var*-1
  
  
  if (fisher_transform_icc) {
    # We can safely transform before we flip to calculate c_ED or doing filtering, because fisher transform is
    # symmetrical around 0 and retains 0s.
    c_dat$c_nonED <- psych::fisherz(c_dat$c_nonED)
  }
  
  c_dat$c_ED <- c_dat$c_nonED*-1
  
  c_dat <- c_dat %>% group_by(...) %>% mutate(L2_nonED = sum(m_ED, na.rm = TRUE)/(n()-1))
  
  c_dat$L2_ED <- c_dat$L2_nonED*-1
  
  if (!allow_neg_icc) {
    # Set all measures of emotion differentiation to NA if the c_ED is negative
    c_dat <- c_dat %>% mutate(across(c('m_nonED', 'm_ED', 'c_nonED', 'c_ED', 'L2_nonED', 'L2_ED'),
                                     function(x) ifelse(c_nonED < 0, NA, x)))
  }
  
  
  out <- left_join(dat, select(c_dat, row_id, m_nonED, m_ED, c_nonED, c_ED, L2_nonED, L2_ED)) %>% select(-row_id)
  
  return(out)
}

dataset1 <- calculate_ed(dat = meal_only_emo, emotions = c("Alert","Inspired","Determined", "Attentive", "Active"), record_id, 
                         allow_neg_icc = FALSE, fisher_transform_icc = TRUE)

In my attempts to debug, I'm finding that the function seems to fail at the section that says "# Calculate person-level metrics"

None of your columns are vectors, because of the attributes added from importing from a SPSS file (i think?). utils:::stack.data.frame which is the root of the error has code explicitly checking the results of is.vector across your data.frame. Try something like meal_only_emo[] <- lapply(meal_only_emo, as.integer) and see if that then allows your code to run. I can't test this at my current setup to know if it works or not.

I totally overlooked this. My boss still uses SPSS for everything and I neglected to consider that they ran this through SPSS first (which is also likely why the full dataset is so messy...). While your suggestion is giving me a new error related to factor levels, this is getting on the right track. I think I can workshop from here. Awesome.

While the hint by user @thelatemail solves your problem
library(dplyr) # we do not need more!
calculate_ed(dat = data.frame(lapply(meal_only_emo, as.integer)), 
             emotions = c("Alert","Inspired","Determined", "Attentive", "Active"), 
             record_id, allow_neg_icc = FALSE, fisher_transform_icc = TRUE)

giving
Joining with `by = join_by(record_id, row_id)`
Adding missing grouping variables: `record_id`
Joining with `by = join_by(record_id, row_id)`
  record_id Alert Inspired Determined Attentive Active   m_nonED       m_ED   c_nonED       c_ED  L2_nonED    L2_ED
1         7     4        2          2         2      1 1.2626263 -1.2626263 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
2         7     4        1          2         4      1 0.2020202 -0.2020202 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
3         7     4        2          3         3      3 2.4747475 -2.4747475 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
4         7     4        1          2         2      1 3.2323232 -3.2323232 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
5         7     4        2          2         4      2 0.8080808 -0.8080808 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
6         7     4        2          2         3      3 0.8080808 -0.8080808 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576

and a some inital warnings, I would consider a re-write using base R where possible.
A brute force version which, potentially, can be reduced to a few lines, might be:
f = \(X, emotions, grp, fisher_transform_icc = TRUE, allow_neg_icc = FALSE) {
  X$row_id = seq_along(X)
  l = lapply(split(X, X[grp]), \(x) { x[emotions] = scale(x[emotions], scale=FALSE); x })
  m = do.call("rbind", lapply(l, 
          \(x) cbind(x[c("row_id", "record_id")], 
                     m_emo_var = sum(diag(var(x[emotions]))),
                     c_nonED = psych::ICC(x[emotions], missing = TRUE, lmer = FALSE)$results[6, 2])))
  M = merge(do.call("rbind", l), m)
  
  M$momentary_squared_sum = ( rowMeans(M[emotions]) * length(emotions) )^2L
  M$m_nonED = M$momentary_squared_sum / M$m_emo_var
  M$m_ED = M$momentary_squared_sum / M$m_emo_var*-1
  
  if (fisher_transform_icc) # fisher transform is symm. around 0 + retains 0s
    M$c_nonED = psych::fisherz(M$c_nonED)
  
  M$c_ED = M$c_nonED*-1
  M$L2_nonED = ave(M[["m_ED"]], M[[grp]], FUN = \(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) / (length(x)-1) )  
  M$L2_ED = M$L2_nonED*-1
  
  if (!allow_neg_icc) # Set all values of emotion differentiation to NA if c_ED is neg.
    M[nms] = lapply(M[nms<-grepl("ED$", names(M))], \(x) ifelse(M$c_nonED < 0, NA, x))
  
  merge(X, M[c("row_id", "m_nonED", "m_ED", "c_nonED", "c_ED", "L2_nonED", "L2_ED")]) |>
    subset(select = -row_id)
}

giving
> f(as.data.frame(meal_only_emo), 
+   c("Alert","Inspired","Determined", "Attentive", "Active"),
+   grp = "record_id")
  record_id Alert Inspired Determined Attentive Active   m_nonED       m_ED   c_nonED       c_ED  L2_nonED    L2_ED
1         7     4        2          2         2      1 1.2626263 -1.2626263 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
2         7     4        1          2         4      1 0.2020202 -0.2020202 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
3         7     4        2          3         3      3 2.4747475 -2.4747475 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
4         7     4        1          2         2      1 3.2323232 -3.2323232 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
5         7     4        2          2         4      2 0.8080808 -0.8080808 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576
6         7     4        2          2         3      3 0.8080808 -0.8080808 0.6024535 -0.6024535 -1.757576 1.757576

~ reduced package dependencies = longer code life span
Probably, I will come back and revise. I have not tested the code. Different record_ids would be required for this.

ahh yes this is timeseries data so our record_ids are repeated. We have about 44 repeats per person due to the protocol. This could create issues for these solutions I'm realizing
